# What is the right way to run downloaded project developed by yii to my local server

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Recently, I have downloaded a project developed in yii but when I tried to run this project to my local server using XAMPP, I got the following errors.

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-tutorial-master\web/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-tutorial-master\web\index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-tutorial-master\web/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-tutorial-master\web\index.php on line 7

I want to know if there are some procedures to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your errors

Comment: Please check the errors are added

Comment: from the information provided so far, looks like you need to run composer install or composer update command to generate Composer autload files

Comment: Are you positively sure that the file exists? As Bilal points out, it feels you haven't installed dependencies.

Comment: Yes,I don't have the composer inside the project.I will try with composer update.But, is that the right way of running the downloaded project in yii to local server...

Comment: Well, Same things happened when I move my project from wamp server to xampp server in my local server. I have installed and updated the composer but still errors are showing..

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpYiiFramework/../yii/framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpYiiFramework\index.php on line 15

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpYiiFramework/../yii/framework/yii.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpYiiFramework\index.php on line 15

Comment: need to update dependencies. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chc37leP9vk   refer this link